# Improve the resolution of png generated with R

Tags: r, network-programming, png, resolution, igraph

I created some networks through `R` and the `IGRAPH package` in `.png` files. My goal would be to make a little video to show how the topology of the network changes through the time. Only that the resolution of the `.png` files is really low. Is there a way that would generate the same file but with an higher resolution? My colleague with his PC and using the same `R script` generated networks with an higher resolution.

Here is my code:

```
wd<-getwd()
setwd(wd)
library(Matrix)
library(igraph)
library(slam)

plotname<-sprintf("g_communities_t%03d.png",t)
png(filename=plotname, height=640, width=640)
plot(community.infomap[[t]],g1[[t]],layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,vertex.label=NA,edge.arrow.size=1,edge.curved=TRUE,vertex.size=2+sqrt(vertex.weight[[t]]))
dev.off()
```

Thanks to all

Comment: You may want to print as .pdf or .eps for a better resolution (they should be better scalable). I don't have the "community.infomap" type example to try it out myself.

For even better results you may look at R plot: size and resolution and http://www.r-bloggers.com/high-resolution-figures-in-r/

Comment: you may also prefer use `dev.copy` which I guess is easier for saving lots of pictures

Comment: How can I use `dev.copy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `png`'s `res` parameter to adjust nominal resolution. Note that is a good idea to adjust values vor height and width accordingly in order to preserve text size etc.:

```
resfactor = 3
png(filename=plotname, res = 72*resfactor, height=640*resfactor, width=640*resfactor)
```

`? png` gives you more details (also see `? dev.copy` to copy the graphics contents of the current device to another).